# Как добавить условия для #include?

Tags: c++, c

Я собираюсь подключать файлы за папкой проекта, таким образом `#include "../file.h"`

И что бы каждый раз не повторять `../` мне нужен способ заставить компилятор понимать что `#include "file.h"` это `#include "../file.h"`

Я кажется нашел решение, оно довольно простое.

Нужно создать один файл где функция main и этот файл будет иметь путь `../file.h`
Но зато все остальные файлы в нем могут иметь путь `#include "file.h"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам стоит добавить в вопрос информацию о используемой системе сборки.

Например у CMake для этого есть [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/target_include_directories.html), а у MsBuild свойство [`AdditionalIncludeDirectories`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=vs-2019).

Если вы вызываете компилятор самостоятельно, из консоли, то у каждого есть опция, позволяющая задать диретории, где искать заголовочые файлы. Например `-I` у GCC и `/I` у MSVC.

Comment: Я не знаю что такое CMake собираю пока что в VS, CMake  это наверно для linux

Comment: нет, можно генерировать vsproj CMake'ом

Answer (score 0):

Для этого существует вариант `#include <file.h>` и параметр компилятора для указания списка каталогов для поиска файлов в угловых скобках. Сам параметр ищите в документации по компилятору и/или IDE

Comment: Где можно список посмотреть в которых он ищет файлы?

Comment: Для меня вероятно не подойдет такой способ, он кажется ищет файлы где находиться компилятор. А мне нужно искать в папки проекта или что бы я мог сам указать путь где искать.